Multiplicity of bilateral shift on a Banach space
Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a Banach space. A bijective linear map $V: \mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{X}$ is said to be a bilateral shift if there is a closed subspace $\mathbb{L}$ of $\mathbb{X}$ such that
$\mathbb{X} = \displaystyle\bigoplus_{n=-\infty}^\infty V^n \mathbb{L}$, where the direct sum means every element $x\in \mathbb{X}$ can be uniquely represented as convergent series $x= \displaystyle \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty V^n l_n$, where $l_n \in \mathbb{L}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. The subspace $\mathbb{L}$ is known as generating subspace of $V$.
Note that generating subspace of $V$ may not be unique. Because if $\mathbb{E}$ is a generating subspace of $V$, then $V\mathbb{E}$ is also a generating subspace of $V$.
Doubt: Whether any two generating subspaces of $V$ have same dimension ?
What I have done: If $\mathbb{L}_1$ and $\mathbb{L}_2$ are two infinite dimensional generating subspaces of $V$, then we have $\dim(\mathbb{L}_1)\cdot \aleph_0 = \dim(\mathbb{L}_2)\cdot \aleph_0$, which implies $\dim(\mathbb{L}_1) = \dim(\mathbb{L}_2)$.
How to do if one of $\mathbb{L}_1$ and $\mathbb{L}_2$ has finite dimension?
Thanks for any ideas.

In "what you have done", why should $\dim(\mathbb{L}_1)\cdot \aleph_0 = \dim(\mathbb{L}_2)\cdot \aleph_0$?

Because if $\mathbb{L}$ is a generating subspace, then $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{n=-\infty}^\infty V^n \mathbb{L}$ has dimension $\dim (\mathbb{L})\cdot \aleph_0$.

No it doesn't because this "direct sum" is not algebraic, as you explained yourself: an element of it is a series, not a finite sum.
